# Issue with Token Publishing on Solana Network @solana

Tags: solana

I have encountered an issue while trying to publish a token on the Solana network. Despite my efforts, I have been unable to successfully publish the token.

Here are the details of the situation:

```
Token Information:

Name: Verusia (VRSA)
Metadata URL: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qme8Yr9rP3o33p7GmSaeC5vbxx7bQSdyun7ZgR9PCyfWoA?filename=main.json
Token Address: A1qMHGjw2tJQGyAPnjrVkH532Pys7CLRKoBsoCuk8y4Y
Additional Information:

Token Logo: https://github.com/NilsZer1/Crypto/blob/main/logo.png?raw=true
Description: Token based on the Solana blockchain
Properties: Type - Currency
Tags: Cryptocurrency
```

Despite my initial attempt to publish the token using GitHub, I have encountered technical limitations that prevent me from proceeding further. As a result, I have sought alternative methods to ensure the token's successful publication. Unfortunately, my efforts have been met with challenges, and I find myself unable to resolve this matter independently.

The token appears as "unrecognized" on Solscan.

I am committed to ensuring the accurate and compliant issuance of the token.

I initially attempted to publish the token using GitHub as the platform for issuance. I meticulously provided all necessary token details, including the token's name (Verusia), symbol (VRSA), decimals (18), and metadata URL (https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qme8Yr9rP3o33p7GmSaeC5vbxx7bQSdyun7ZgR9PCyfWoA?filename=main.json). Moreover, I provided an additional repository link for the token logo (https://github.com/NilsZer1/Crypto/blob/main/logo.png?raw=true) and specified the token's description, properties, and tags.

Comment: The GitHub method that you're mentioning was deprecated over a year ago. You can follow the instructions about how to add token metadata through other methods at https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list#this-repository-is-eol-